# how i can hide/eecrypt AdMob Ad Units in android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob

I was wondering how i can hide Ad Mob Ad Units in my android source code, In case some one downloaded my app from Google and did a reverse engineering on it.

let say this is my ad mob ad unit (Banner)

`ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111`

I have seen how Using engines like Unity to develop games just hides ad units i guess it encrypts it or something, I don't know. if u know please let me know.

Comment: You can't. That's the simplest answer. Although you can make it harder to get by not coding it as a one string. You can also make it harder by assigning the string from the Editor but you can't stop people from getting that. A person with Wireshark does not even have to decompile your app to see that. Save your time for something else.

Comment: Oh, I see, you mentioned Wireshark that freaked me out, how's that work ?

Comment: Or you can retrieve your Admob ID from (your)server and save it using SecurePrefrence

Comment: As long as it is sending it through the network which it does, you can use Wireshark to view the request when connected to the-same network. It might be encrypted but it can be dycrypted too.

Comment: Oh I get it now, I will use your advice, breaking down the admob ad unit to pieces so it can be hard to put into one meaningful peice

Comment: Thanks @Michal_196 and Programmer for all your help.

Comment: @Programmer couldn't you use ProGuard to obfuscate the Ad Unit ID in the source code?

Comment: @DanielStorm ProGuard will only change the name of the variable. It wont obfuscate the string value. Remember that I am not saying that there is no way to protect the string. I am saying that no matter what, a hacker who needs that will get it. As long as it is embedded on that app, it can be retrieved. Assuming that the **Ad Unit ID** is on the server only then it is safe unless the server is hacked. I don't think there is a way to put it in a server like you can with web app keys like Google Map....

Comment: @Programmer I see now. Great points.

Comment: @DanielStorm Great point, i will stick with breaking the string into pieces this will make it hard on them to get the job done knowing that the java will be viewed in .Smali files, as u said probably there is no way around this except the server thing but then again even that can be access or viewed using things like wireshark to sniff the packets, anyway thanks man, you've proved your point, nice and clear.